# How to run Django admin site on Android

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

This is what am facing with with Django on my Android
I'm using Pydroid on my phone. Python and Django are fully functional. But when I try to run Django admin site on Chrome it shows "Server error occurred. Contact administrator" and in the terminal it shows this error:
storage/emulated/0/mysite $ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 28, 2022 - 16:28:28
Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[28/Apr/2022 16:28:45] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[28/Apr/2022 16:28:55] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/zoneinfo/_common.py", line 12, in load_tzdata
    return importlib.resources.open_binary(package_name, resource_name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 88, in open_binary
    package = _get_package(package)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 49, in _get_package
    module = _resolve(package)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 40, in _resolve
    return import_module(name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tzdata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 92, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 389, in render
    tzinfo = timezone.get_current_timezone() if settings.USE_TZ else None
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 84, in get_current_timezone
    return getattr(_active, "value", get_default_timezone())
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 70, in get_default_timezone
    return zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(settings.TIME_ZONE)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/zoneinfo/_common.py", line 24, in load_tzdata
    raise ZoneInfoNotFoundError(f"No time zone found with key {key}")
zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key Africa/Lagos'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/zoneinfo/_common.py", line 12, in load_tzdata
    return importlib.resources.open_binary(package_name, resource_name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 88, in open_binary
    package = _get_package(package)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 49, in _get_package
    module = _resolve(package)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/resources.py", line 40, in _resolve
    return import_module(name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tzdata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 134, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 180, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 66, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 386, in get_traceback_html
    return t.render(c)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1059, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 735, in resolve
    obj = template_localtime(obj, context.use_tz)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 184, in template_localtime
    return localtime(value) if should_convert else value
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 203, in localtime
    timezone = get_current_timezone()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 84, in get_current_timezone
    return getattr(_active, "value", get_default_timezone())
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 70, in get_

    default_timezone
        return zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(settings.TIME_ZONE)
      File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/zoneinfo/_common.py", line 24, in load_tzdata
        raise
```

Comment: Try install `tzdata` according to the traceback mentioned above, `pip install tzlocal` and `pip install tzdata` and re-run the `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pyroid,
install termux terminal on Android and later open the termux terminal and run:

pkg install python

pip install django

django-admin startproject first

vim first/first/settings.py

Then in settings.py add,

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

After saving the settings.py and
run

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

and it will run on localhost:8000 on your browser

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pydroid app and have this problem.

Go the terminal and type `pip install tzdata`

After you install `tzdata` start the Django server again and you should be fine.

Thanks.